# How to make a shiny app that allows to draw multiple polygons on raster images?

Tags: r, shiny, raster, r-raster, terra

I want to develop a `shiny` app where users can draw a polygon on a `raster` image. As soon as the user finishes drawing a polygon, I want the app to show them a table of chosen pixels.

For example, `terra` provides a function `draw` that can be used as `draw("polygon")`. But, I cannot make it work with my `shiny` app.

The basic idea of the app is as follows (I have commented the problematic parts with `#`):

```
library(terra)
library(shiny)

r = rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

ui = fluidPage(
        plotOutput("map"),
        tableOutput("chosen_pixels")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$map = renderPlot({
                plot(r)
                # draw("polygon") # I comment it otherwise the app does not run
        })
        
        # output$chosen_pixels = renderPlot({
                # here I want to write code that shows a table of chosen pixels
        #})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  textInput("polygon_name", label = "Polygon name", value = "polygon 1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  coords <- reactiveVal(value = tibble(x = numeric(), y = numeric(), name = character()))

  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    add_row(coords(),
      x = isolate(input$plot_click$x),
      y = isolate(input$plot_click$y),
      name = isolate(input$polygon_name)
    ) %>% coords()
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(r)
    
    coords() %>%
      nest(-name) %>%
      deframe() %>%
      map(~ polygon(.x$x, .x$y))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(coords())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice approach! At the moment I cannot escape the drawn polygon. Is there a way to "refresh" it so that the user can start making new polygons somewhere else?

Comment: @bird I added a new input to name the polygon. A new polygon will be created whenever the name changes.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. `isolate()` is not needed. `nest(cols = -name)` avoids a warning.

Comment: Works great, neat solution, thnx